# Template class spezialisation missing member

Tags: c++, templates

I wanted to create a simple template class having a member variable `ret`. For some reason my MSVC 2010 compiler complains, that there is no declared variable named `ret` in `Converter<double>`. I'm really clueless, why?

```
template<typename M>
struct Converter  {
    M ret;

    void operator()(const int& value) {
        throw std::exception("Not implemented!");
    }
};

template<>
struct Converter<double> {
    void operator()(const int& value) {
        ret=value;
    }
};

int main() {
    Converter<int> x;
}
```

Comment: "that there is no declared variable named ret in `Converter<double>`" Could you point out where you'd find the definition of `ret` in `Converter<double>` :) ?

Comment: I thought in `template<typename M> struct Converter`, but this is seemingly a misconception. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Theres no inheritance going on, so theres no `ret` in scope. I just think the best answers are the ones that can be self-resolved (eg. providing your own answer).

Comment: I totally I agree, but I just didn't got it. Even after looking at it for ages. :-|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is another class (there is no inheritance or any other depenency here):

```
template<>
struct Converter<double> {
    double ret;
    void operator()(const int& value) {
        ret=value;
    }
};
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `double ret`?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is already marked solved, but I thought I should just clarify this further.
`Converter<double>` and `Converter<int>` are different separate classes, so `ret` would not be defined in your double variation until you declare it as one of its members.

Regardless, it appears what you're trying to achieve is inheritance, which can be done in a similar way:

```
template<typename M>
struct AbstractConverter  { // you could call it 'Converter' too, and it'll work as you expect
    M ret;

    virtual void operator()(const int& value) {
        throw std::exception("Not implemented!");
    }
    //or 
    virtual void operator(const int &value) = 0; //pure virtual
    // will not compile if someone wants to use it directly
};

template<>
struct Converter<double> : public AbstractConverter<double>{
    void operator()(const int& value) { // we implement the operator here
        ret=value;
    }
};
```